# How to print data in controller by using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning Ruby on Rails from the internet and building one small project. I found some issue. I searched in google to print my data in controller. all are suggest me use `puts` but I have tried in `puts` not getting any output. here is my code:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @categories = Category.includes(:galleries).where(:is_active=> 1)

  @categories.each do |catt|
    puts catt.name
  end
end
```

Also I got some comment in my previous question they suggest me use `render` so I tried this code:

```
  @categories.each do |catt|
    render text:catt.inspect
  end
  return false
```

Here i am getting error message for using `render`

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Can you please say me how to get my both string and array record in my controller?

Comment: You dont render data in the controller. The controller send the data to the views where is rendered.

Comment: You can only call render once in a method not in loop

Comment: @Thorin you are right but how to get my all categories record in my controller?

Comment: First why you need this ?? if you need on controller for debugging only then you should use some debugging gem like https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Comment: The only way you can "Print" the data is using puts and starting the server through the Terminal, or the console (it's the same). This only will be valid for debugging and you have gems to do that already

Answer (score 1):

You can send those values to the server's log file:

```
@categories.each do |catt|
  Rails.logger.debug "Category Name: #{catt.name}" 
end
```

You can open and monitor the log file for changes with the `tail` command:

```
$ tail -f log/development.log
```

Comment: I have successfully installed tail in this command - `gem install tail`. But How to use `tail` in my local file. can you briefly describe here. I am getting confuse.

Comment: [`tail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) is a command on unix systems. There is no need to install a gem for that. Just call the above command in your console when you are on Linux or Mac. That line will not work on Windows. I am not sure if there is any equivalent on Windows.

Comment: I am using windows. :(

Comment: There are severals other [Ways to Tail a Log File on Windows](http://stackify.com/11-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/).

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  @categories = Category.includes(:galleries).where(:is_active=> 1)

  @categories.each do |catt|
    catt.name
    Rails.logger.info "This is cat name: #{catt.name}"
  end
end
```

You can use logger.info and check the logs

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you'd append where to find those log files and how to view them to your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can only call render once per action/method, and puts doesn't work in this context. Also, render :text sets the response type as 'text/html'. Do you want plain text instead? If so, maybe use the below? Or you can override the response type, if you'd rather.

```
  @result = ''
  @categories.each do |catt|
    @result += catt.inspect + '\n'
  end
  render plain: @result
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create a empty view where to print the output variable with puts command.

Comment: index.html.erb view is there. But I want to view my database table details in my controller.

Comment: Use Rails.log.debug for save data to file. Use an editor to view result. "tail" is a linux command.